# Cannot Get Pyglet To Render

Tags: python, pyglet

I am attempting to build a small API to simplify some things when using pyglet. I want it to be as similar to Processing syntax, so that I can use my Python Processing code in a pure python environment instead of the processing one.

I have gotten some code to work to draw a rectangle, but it only works when I copy / paste. The model I am using at the moment does not seem to do anything.

Here is the important parts of the App class that I am using:

```
import pyglet
class App(pyglet.window.Window):
    def __init__(self, w=1280, h=720, fullscreen = False, resizable = True):
        super(App, self).__init__(w, h, fullscreen = fullscreen, resizable=resizable)
        self.size = self.width, self.height = w, h
        self.alive = 1
    def on_draw(self):
        self.render()
    def setBinds(self, drawFunction):
        self.drawFunction = drawFunction
    def render(self):
        self.clear()
        self.drawFunction()
        self.flip()
    def run(self):
        while self.alive == 1:
            self.render()
            event = self.dispatch_events()
    def Rect(self, x, y, w, h):
        pyglet.graphics.draw(4, pyglet.gl.GL_QUADS, ('v2f', [x, y, w, y, w, h, x, h]))
```

Here is the code to run the application. It should open a window and then every frame draw a rectangle to the screen.

```
from processing import App
def draw(dt=0):
    width, height = APP.width, APP.height
    APP.Rect(100,100,100,100)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    APP = App()
    APP.setBinds(drawFunction=draw)
    APP.run()
```

However it does not draw anything to the screen. No errors are displayed or anything, just a blank black screen.
I have gotten the pyglet.grapics.draw function to draw things on the screen when using simplified code such as:

```
import pyglet
from pyglet.window import mouse

window = pyglet.window.Window()

@window.event
def on_draw():
    window.clear()
    x, y, dx, dy = 100, 100, 20, 30
    pyglet.graphics.draw(4, pyglet.gl.GL_QUADS, ('v2f', [x, y, dx, y, dx, dy, x, dy]))

pyglet.app.run()
```

I am not sure what the difference is between these two sets of code that is making it not work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you call the method `Rect` with the following parameters

> ```
> APP.Rect(100,100,100,100)
> ```

then the instruction

> ```
> pyglet.graphics.draw(4, pyglet.gl.GL_QUADS, ('v2f', [x, y, w, y, w, h, x, h]))
> ```

doesn't draw a rectangle, because all the vertex coordinates are identical.

To draw a rectangle you've to calculate the right and top vertex coordinates by `x+w` respectively `y+h`:

```py
x1, y1, x2, y2 = x, y, x+w, y+h 
pyglet.graphics.draw(4, pyglet.gl.GL_QUADS, ('v2f', [x1, y1, x2, y1, x2, y2, x1, y2]))
```